# extend "private method" in a define module via mixin

Tags: magento2.2, uicomponent

Let's say we have a class that returns a Magento uiComponent, that I want to extend (original.js)

```
/* file name: original.js */
define(['uiComponent'],function(Component){
    'use strict';
    //here's the internal method
    function private() {
        return 'private';
    }

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            private();
        }
    });
})
```

Here's the mixin declaration (requirejs-config.js)

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'original': {
                'original-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then, the mixin (original-mixin.js)

```
/* file name: original-mixin.js */
define([], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (original) {
        return original.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                console.log(this.private); //obviously not working
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I hope the above is self-explanatory of what I'm trying to achieve. Basically I wanted to override the internal "private" function with a mixin. Thanks for your kind help.